# Case when with aggregation in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data of how much users spend in several games in BigQuery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS user_values (
  user_id int,
  value float,
  game char
);

INSERT INTO user_values VALUES
(1, 10, 'A'),
(1, 10, 'A'),
(1, 2, 'A'),
(1, 4, 'B'),
(1, 5, 'B'),
(2, 0, 'A'),
(2, 10, 'B'),
(2, 6, 'B');
```

I want to check, for every user, if they've spent more than 20 in game A and more than 15 in game B. In this case, the output table should be:

```
user_id,game,spent_more_than_cutoff
1,A,TRUE
1,B,FALSE
2,A,FALSE
2,B,TRUE
```

I want to do this for an arbitrary number of users and 5-10 games. I've tried this:

```sql
    select
        game,
        user_id,
        case
            when sum(value) > 20 and game = 'A' then TRUE
            when sum(value) > 15 and game = 'B' then TRUE
            else FALSE
        end as spent_more_than_cutoff,
    from user_values
    group by 1, 2
```

but I get thrown the following error:

*Column 3 contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [19:20]*

What's the simplest way of doing this in BigQuery without needing to do different queries for different games?

Is there an `all` function that can help to do something like this?

```sql
    select
        game,
        user_id,
        case
            when sum(value) > 20 and all(game) = 'A' then TRUE
            when sum(value) > 15 and all(game) = 'B' then TRUE
            else FALSE
        end as spent_more_than_cutoff,
    from user_values
    group by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do this for an arbitrary number of users and 5-10 games

Consider below approach

```
with cutoffs as (
  select 'A' game, 20 cutoff union all 
  select 'B', 15
)
select user_id, game, 
  sum(value) > any_value(cutoff) spent_more_than_cutoff
from user_values
left join cutoffs using(game)
group by user_id, game
```

If applied to sample data for `user_values` in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The expression for filtering on the `game` needs to be the *argument* to the `sum()`:

```
select game, user_id,
       (sum(case when game = 'A' then value end) > 20 and
        sum(case when game = 'B' then value end) > 15 
       ) as spent_more_than_cutoff
from user_values
group by 1, 2;
```

Note that you are returning a boolean so no `case` is needed.

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . Does this not do what you are asking for?  It seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select game,
       user_id,
       sum(if(game = 'A', value, 0)) > 20 or sum(if(game = 'B', value, 0)) > 15 as spent_more_than_cutoff
from user_values
group by 1, 2;
```